# Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string. when I trying to pass byte[]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying send `Byte[]` by converting to string from View to controller in `@Html.ActionLink`. Evey time when I click on `ActionLink` it is throwing exception. I am attaching code here.

### Exception

[image]

### URL After Action Click

```
  http://localhost:55253/Member/Create?customerContactNumber=0439349
&committeeId=AAAAAAAADLc%3D
```

### View Code

```
    @using VolunteerPoints.BootstrapSupport
    @model Tuple<VolunteerPoints.Models.Contact, IEnumerable<VolunteerPoints.Data.Committee>>

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "SearchResults";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

    <h2>Activity Search Results</h2>
    <table id="Activitieslist" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover .table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Item2.GetEnumerator().Current.Committee_Name)
                </th>

                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Item2.GetEnumerator().Current.Committee_Type)
                </th>

                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach (var model in Model.Item2)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => model.Committee_Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => model.Committee_Type)
                </td>

                <td>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Select", "Create","Member", new 

{customerContactNumber = Model.Item1.Number, committeeId = 
Convert.ToBase64String(model.Committee_Id) }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>

    @section Scripts {
              @Styles.Render("~/Content/DataTables/css")
            @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/DataTables") 

        <script type="text/JavaScript">
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $('#Activitieslist').dataTable({
                    "bSort": true,
                    "bPaginate": false,
                    "bAutoWidth": false,
                });

            });
        </script>
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Well this part of the URL:

```
AAAAAAAADLc%3D
```

should be decoded to

```
AAAAAAAADLc=
```

... at which point the length is a multiple of 4, with perfectly reasonable padding at the end.

So I suspect the problem is how/whether the decoding is performed.

(As a side note: `byte[]` is a pretty unusual representation for an ID. Do you really need it to be done that way?)

Comment: Yes, @Jon. It is external Pivotal database designed that way. How can padding this?

Comment: I have added `=` in the url after exception and entered for execution. Still error is the same.

Comment: @James123: Well `Convert.FromBase64String("AAAAAAAADLc=")` works for me without throwing an exception - so you should really debug into it to find out what *is* being passed to `FromBase64String`.

Comment: I don't really understand is I am using `Convert.ToBase64String` and why exception is showing `Convert.FromBase64String`??

Comment: @James123: Because presumably the string you're giving is being "corrupted" in some form - I suspect it's being URL-encoded but not URL-decoded. An alternative would be to use a more web-safe form of Base64 encoding. (See the Wikipedia page for details, IIRC.)

Comment: Then what is my solution? confusing. How can I pass these ids back to controller? Any other way?

Comment: @James123: You should probably look into the documentation for how URL encoding is managed around bindings. There may be a way of forcing either more decoding or less encoding. After all, it should be feasible to have a *string* value ending with an `=` for other reasons. The first thing I'd do is create a tiny, tiny application which *just* has a model with this in, so you can experiment without the rest of your app.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the section of code:

```
committeeId = Convert.ToBase64String(model.Committee_Id)
```

To

```
committeeId = HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(model.Committee_Id)
```

This will provide a more URL friendly encrypted string which will avoid characters in the URL that may cause errors.

Hope this helps you James123;